# Loader library comparsion: bulkloader, loadermax, queueloader

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I've been using different loaders in the past, here are the most popular:

- **bulkloader** by arthur debert: https://github.com/arthur-debert/BulkLoader
- **loadermax** by greensock: http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/
- **queueloader** by hydrotic: https://github.com/hydrotik/QueueLoader/wiki/

*Which one is the best one and for which challenges?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loadermax has a smaller filesize than bulkloader and has a lot of nice extras like for example nest loaders in each other).

It's sort of a bulkloader on steroids. You should check out it's features @ http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/

I've been using bulkloader for a few years now, and it's very good, though loadermax is just that little extra that's worth your while (and can be as small as 7k)...

(I don't know about queue-loader though)

Answer (score 1):

Another consideration in comparison is licensing.
BulkLoader is licensed under the very liberal MIT license.  Whereas LoaderMax is licensed by GreenSock for free usage in free websites/software.  If you charge a fee for your website or software you'll need to purchase a recurring corporate membership license from GreenSock (currently $150/year).